# Send form information to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I designed a flash card and I want to change the text of the card when I click on the button, but I do not know how to send the form information to the App component to update the state.
App component

```
function App() {
      const [flashCard, setFlashCard] = useState({
        word: "test",
        persianEquivalent: "test",
      });
      const setFlashCardHandler = (e) => {
        setFlashCard({ flashCard: e });
      };
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <Form setFlashCard={setFlashCardHandler} />
          <FlashCard flashCard={flashCard} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
export default App;
```

Form component:

```
  function Form({ setFlashCard }) {
      const [valueEn, setValueEn] = useState();
      const [valuePer, setValuePer] = useState();
      const setValueHandlerEn = (e) => {
        setValueEn(e.target.value);
      };
      const setValueHandlerPer = (e) => {
        setValuePer(e.target.value);
      };
      const setFlashCardHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setFlashCard((e)=>{valueEn=e.target[0].value});
      };
      return (
        <form onSubmit={setFlashCardHandler}>
          <input
            id="word-input"
            placeholder="world"
            value={valueEn}
            onChange={setValueHandlerEn}
          />
          <input
            id="persian-equivalent-input"
            placeholder="Equivalent"
            value={valuePer}
            onChange={setValueHandlerPer}
          />
          <button id="submit-btn">send</button>
        </form>
      );
    }
    
    export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add new updateFlashCard props to to component.

Like:

```
<Form updateFlashCard={(e) => setFlashCard(e)}/>
```

And change value in `updateFlashCard` state from form component

Like:

```
function Form({ updateFlashCard }) {
      const [valueEn, setValueEn] = useState();
      const [valuePer, setValuePer] = useState();
      const setValueHandlerEn = (e) => {
        setValueEn(e.target.value);
      };
      const setValueHandlerPer = (e) => {
        setValuePer(e.target.value);
      };
      const setFlashCardHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();


        updateFlashCard(e.target[0].value) // update from here

     
      };
      return (
        <form onSubmit={setFlashCardHandler}>
          <input
            id="word-input"
            placeholder="world"
            value={valueEn}
            onChange={setValueHandlerEn}
          />
          <input
            id="persian-equivalent-input"
            placeholder="Equivalent"
            value={valuePer}
            onChange={setValueHandlerPer}
          />
          <button id="submit-btn">send</button>
        </form>
      );
    }
    
    export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with how you set values.

1. Pass `setFlashCard` as the prop to `Form`

```
<Form setFlashCard={setFlashCard} />
```

2. In Form change the `setFlashCardHandler` as below.

```
  const setFlashCardHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFlashCard({ word: valueEn, persianEquivalent: valuePer });
  };
```

3. Set empty string (`""`) as default state to avoid sending `undefined`.

```
  const [valueEn, setValueEn] = useState("");
  const [valuePer, setValuePer] = useState("");
```

[image: Edit proud-water-2xz9y]

Comment: @samaneh rajaee, let me know if you still have issues?

Comment: thanks for your answer
But when sending in the set Flash Card function
undefined is sent
In the Form component

Comment: Yes, I made changes but the issue was not resolved

Comment: Thanks, the problem was solved with a few changes